lost sync with arduino while turning on roboclaw
I have a system that consists of two roboclaw motor controllers and an Arduino Mega. Both the roboclaws are connected to the Ubuntu PC over USB cables and are operated using the roboclaw ros package provided by sonycd. I also have an Arduino that is connected over the USB cable to my Pc and I use it to bridge my VL53L4CD sensors to the ROS environment.
The arduino functions fine and I get the data from the VL53L4CD sensors when the arduino communication is established using rosserial package. However, as soon as I turn on my motors using the roboclaw motor controllers, the arduino communication crashes. This crash happens even when im not using the rosserial and just using my serial monitor to observe the data. I have tried using a differnt PC and every time the Arduino crashes as soon as I start the motor controllers.
Is there anyone else who has faced the same problem? Or if anyone knows any underlying problem here, it could really be helpful for me.
